# CSS Div with Scroll & Triangle like arrow on the right

Tags: html, css

I have a div for which I need to show an arrow to it, it works fine when I do not put `overflow: scroll` property to it.

```css
.description {
  position: relative;
  /* margin: 3em; */
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 170px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 11px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: scroll;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.description::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: -0.5em;
  bottom: -1em;
  left: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 0.5em solid black;
  border-color: transparent transparent black black;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div id="com" class="description">
  Some text
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uzbe71hq/1/

I cannot change the position from `absolute` to `relative` as I need it for positioning of the div.

As you can see the arrow is coming inside the div instead of outside the div. Also how do I show the arrow on the right side of the div?

Comment: wrap that div in another div and put the arrow and border on the outer div and keep the dimensions and overflow on the inner div.  This will help with the arrow: http://www.cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: Any other possibility to have without additional wrapper?